# How do I display a select dropdown list when one option on another select dropdown is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I want to display a select element when an option of another select element is selected, and hide it when another option is selected.

To be more specific, I have 3 dropdowns, one for country, one for province/state and one for city. I want the city dropdown to display when the country is United States and the dropdown should be according to the state selected. I also want the city dropdown to disappear when Canada is selected, regardless of the province selected.

So far, I've got the state/provinces to change according to the country, but I don't know how to remove the whole city element when Canada is selected.

I have this in a jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jascd6ue/

This is my select html code

```
   Country:
<select name="country" class="country">
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
    <option value="United_States">United States</option>
</select>
<br>Province/State:
<select name="pro" class="pro">
    <option value="BC">British Columbia</option>
    <option value="Ontario">Ontario</option>
</select>
```

And this is the Javascript:

```
$('.country').on('change', function (e) {

    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
if(valueSelected == "Canada") {
$('.pro').html('<option value ="BC">British Columbia</option><option value="Ontario">Ontario</option>');
    // remove the city <select> dropdown
               } else if (valueSelected == "United_States") {
$('.pro ').html('<option value ="FL">Florida</option><option value="NY">New York</option>');
}
});
$('.pro').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelectedb = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelectedb = this.value;
    if(valueSelectedb == "Florida") {
    // write <select name="city" class="city"><option value="Miami">Miami</option><option value="Orlando">Orlando</option> </select>
    } else if(valueSelectedb == "New York") {
//    write <select name="city" class="city"><option value="New York">New York</option><option value="Buffalo">Buffalo</option></select>
    }   
});
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: So you want it to add another select field for city based on the state that is selected?

Comment: @ChrisJ Yes, I want the cities to change by state too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/jascd6ue/1/

```
$('.country').on('change', function (e) {

    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    if (valueSelected == "Canada") {
        $('.pro').html('<option value ="BC">British Columbia</option><option value="Ontario">Ontario</option>');
        // remove the city <select> dropdown
    } else if (valueSelected == "United_States") {
        $('.pro ').html('<option value ="FL">Florida</option><option value="NY">New York</option>');
    }
});
$('.pro').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelectedb = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelectedb = this.value;
    console.log(valueSelectedb);
    $(".city option").remove();
    if (valueSelectedb == "FL") {
        $(".city").append("<option value=\"Miami\">Miami</option><option value=\"Orlando\">Orlando</option>");
    } else if (valueSelectedb == "NY") {
        $(".city").append("<option value=\"New York\">New York</option><option value=\"Buffalo\">Buffalo</option></select>");
    }
});
```

I would change this code some though. You could write arrays with all the states and the cities and then use a loop to generate the options